# Running repairs on a node very low on disk space

Tags: cassandra

I inherited a Cassandra cluster roughly a month ago with a new job. I am very experienced with relational DBs but new to Cassandra. I have a two fold question.

One, I have an immediate need with both completing a repair and not running out of space while doing so. The Cassandra cluster has 7 nodes and two ports on each node. The node in question currently has the three directories at 96%, 95%, and 93%. The repair I am running is specific to node, port, keyspace, and table. I have run the directories in question up to 99% with my two previous attempts at running the repair. I want to deal with the space issue before I start my third attempt. I am not sure throwing additional hardware at the issue is possible, I am pursuing that now. I have looked into removing snapshots but I see none on the current node. Would moving data to another node be an option and can someone supply me the commands for doing so? My other nodes are in the 70s space wise.

Two, can someone recommend me a good course on Udemy, Coursera, etc for getting up to speed with Cassandra?

Thank you,
Long time reader, first time question, Joe

I have run the repair twice and had to stop it each time because of space.

Comment: For DB admin/operations questions, such as installation, upgrades, operations, repairs, etc., please post at [Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra)

Comment: Also, do not combine multiple questions in a single question, instead please open a separate question. Having said that, the best place to get to know about Apache Cassandra is at [DataStax Academy](https://datastax.academy).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on becoming a Cassandra admin!

Data is distributed (partitioned) across nodes in a Cassandra cluster, with each node owning a range(s) of "tokens" where each Cassandra partition (equivalent to a database record) gets mapped to a token which then determines which node the partition is stored.

So to answer your first question, it is not possible to move data to another node because (1) the other node(s) won't necessarily own the data, and (2) it would negate how Cassandra distributes data across the cluster.

You really need to address the space issue first like by (3) adding disk space to the affected volumes, and/or (4) adding more nodes so data automatically gets distributed further so each node own less data.

Second, you've mentioned ports multiple times in your post but they're not really relevant. For some context, the default ports are:

- CQL client port `9042` that apps/clients connect to
- gossip port `7000` used for inter-node (private) communication
- JMX port `7199` for admin access by tools such as `nodetool` and monitoring

Finally, [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) is a fantastic resource including free hands-on tutorials. I recommend the free [Cassandra Fundamentals](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals) learning series in particular where you can quickly learn about the basic concepts through short hands-on labs. Everything you need for the courses/tutorials are provided.

If you'd like to invest a bit more time into it, there are instructor-led courses at [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) which range from a few days to a couple of weeks -- all free of charge. Cheers!